# Why is mod_rewrite adding var/www/html to the resulting url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make my service backward compatible, since I have moved the service to a new path internaly, I still want the users to access it with the old url as not all of them have knowledge of this change.

I can accomplish what I want if I add [R] flag at the end of  my rewrite rule but it redirects the url on the client side, which I don't want.

My rewrite code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/old-path(.*)$ /new-path/$ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Although this rule results in the following url:

> /var/www/html/new-path

Sample request looks something like:

> https://host-name/old-path/param1/param2/param3/param4

and rewrite rule should just replace old-path with the new-path.

Can anyone give me some clues about what am I doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the submask is `$1`, not `/$`

Comment: Very true! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are aiming for 'hiding' the rewrite, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/old-path/(.*)$ /new-path/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

And if you REALLY want to extract the hostname:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
  RewriteRule ^/old-path/(.*)$ http://%1/new-path/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

Since %1 references the first bracket of RewriteCond-line...
If you want customers to be rewritten to the new URI and see that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/old-path/(.*)$ https://host-name/new-path/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**or in short, and without even using a rewrite:**

```
RedirectMatch ^/old-path/(.*)$ /new-path/$1
```

To avoid 'https://host-name/' change your DocumentRoot to the parent-directory of 'old-path' and especially 'new-path'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. I can't really give any specific hostname there, it should continue the request with the hostname it was called with.

Comment: I tried your third suggestion, and now I get the following response when I call the old path using curl

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://host-name/new-path/param1/param2/param3/param4">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 10.192.129.55 Port 443</address>
</body></html>

Comment: Don't worry, was not expecting any specific 'real' names here ;) But did you try those suggested solutions. Did one of them work for you? If not, why not? What did you call (again, mask it), what was your expected result and what did you get instead? :)

Comment: 302 just means that you got redirected, but a document/site was found...that lies within the nature of 'RedirectMatch'

Comment: But the behaviour with redirectmatch is same as using [R] flag in rewriterule. Client gets aware of resource endpoint change. Which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: and I can't really hard code the hostname (in reference to suggestion no 1). Although what could work is if I can extract the hostname from the request and add that in the target url.

Comment: Your updated first suggestion seems to work. It is also very close to what I was trying to do but failed due to some syntax issues I guess. Once again, thanks for quick and valuable responses :)